# How to get the value of Html.Kendo().DatePicker() on change event?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik

I have a Html.Kendo DatePicker.  When I change the date and submitting without losing the focus for the input date, I don't have the correct date that I've selected.

Comment: why when changing Html.Kendo DatePicker manually wihtout clicking the calendar does not take the selected date?

Comment: Please share your code sample.

Comment: you should make the date picker readonly else you have to add many validations later

Answer (score 0):

What does "submitting without losing the focus" mean.  If you are submitting anything back to the server, you have to ensure that the date is making it to the action method in a correct format, and then is being sent back down once the view loads again correctly...

Comment: if a change the date manually and stay in the  datepicker,then i click submit,it does not take the new value for the datepicker it keeps the old one